# Play video/audio when "tabs" are active?

Tags: jquery, html5-video, html5-audio, autoplay

I'm using a plugin that creates full screen slides (http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). A class of "active" is added to a slide when its correlating menu item is clicked. I want that action to trigger audio and video for each slide.

The HTML I have is:

```
<div id="fullpage"> 
    <section class="section" id="one">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" />
    </section>  

    <section class="section" id="two">
        <video class="autoplay"> 
            <source src="media/intro-01.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
            <source src="media/intro-01.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
        </video>
    </section>
</div>
```

The Javascript I've tried is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if($('section#two').hasClass("active")){
        $("video.autoplay").trigger("play");    
   };
});
```

When the plugin puts the class of active on  the section it doesn't start playing the video. I'm stumped and can't seem to find much information out there. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not observing an event and it's only executing at page load.

I've looked at the documentation and there is an `afterLoad` event that fires once the element has been scrolled to. Use that.

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        if(index == 2){
            $("video.autoplay").trigger("play");    
        }
    }
});
```